# Play! Generic model conflict with blob data type

Tags: jpa, playframework, blob, playframework-1.x

I am trying to use the extends GenericModel with a blob data type but am getting the error:

```
Execution error occured in template 
{module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/form.html. Exception raised was 
MissingPropertyException : No such property: id for class: models.Member.
In {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/form.html (around line 56)

#{crud.passwordField name:field.name, value:(currentObject ? currentObject[field.name] : null) /}
#{/if}
#{if field.type == 'binary'}
    #{crud.fileField name:field.name, value:(currentObject ? currentObject[field.name] : null), id:currentObject?.id /}
#{/if}
#{if field.type == 'longtext'}
    #{crud.longtextField name:field.name, value:(currentObject ? currentObject[field.name] : null) /}
#{/if}
```

My model is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "news_feed")
public class NewsFeed extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long news_id;

    public Blob news_image;
    ...
}
```

I don't get the error if I remove the `extends GenericModel` or if i remove the blob. What is causing the problem?

All help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your problem is with blob but with CRUD module handling non standard id name.

In your example, the crud module try to get "currentObject?.id" but your id name is "news_id"

Try to rename your "news_id" field to "id"

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be addressed by the `@Id`? It did work though, thanks!

Comment: @Id set your attribute to be the id for jpa persistence but CRUD module works on conventions that are more strict than jpa